# Javadoc fails with class file for java.lang.FunctionalInterface not found

Tags: android-studio, javadoc

Using Android Studio, I am trying to generate the Javadoc. Under Eclipse it worked fine, but under Android Studio I get the error:

> javadoc: error - com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.FunctionalInterface not found

I am using the Javadoc parameters:

> -bootclasspath C:\Users\rehrlich\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar -Xdoclint:none -encoding UTF-8 -docencoding utf-8 -charset utf-8

Answer (score 4):

Yes. This fails on JDK 1.8. I discovered the change to -bootclasspath was causing the problem. The following -bootclasspath is required:

```
"$(JAVA_HOME)/jre/lib/rt.jar";$(HOME)\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar
```