# Fail to generate Javadoc in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javadoc

I am having a trouble to generate the javadoc in android studio. I refered this link as well even the issue is not resolved. Unfortunately I can not find a solution.

[Javadoc fails with class file for java.lang.FunctionalInterface not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29615243/javadoc-fails-with-class-file-for-java-lang-functionalinterface-not-found)

Error is :

```
javadoc: error - com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException: com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for java.lang.FunctionalInterface not found
```

In other command line arguments : -bootclasspath "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\rt.jar";"path\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar"

Is there any other solution for this. OR Did I miss something to add.

Answer (score 0):

The other solution is to use Android SDK that suppots Java 8 features. I installed in Android Studio SDK with API level 25 and it magically worked. Also I didn't have to change SKD version in project.